# How to use JUNG to draw a graph in a GEF editor

Tags: graph, editor, eclipse-rcp, jung, eclipse-gef

Is it possible to use a JUNG graph to display model data in a GEF Editor for an RCP application, rather than using `Figures`, etc. from GEF itself? I'd like to use JUNG to draw a graph for my model, but still be able to use stuff like the flyout palette, the `ScalableFreeformLayeredPane` and other GEF goodies. The graph should remain editable via GEF on-board means. I just think that JUNG has better algorithms for drawing the actual graph.

Has anyone succeeded in doing that or has any examples/starting points for me?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that. GEF is build on top of draw2d, and it is not easy to change this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Will need to find another way to nice grpah layout then :).

Comment: Don't think you can use Zest in a GEF Editor, or can you?

Comment: If you only want to display data why do you need an editor?  You can use a view.

Comment: Ah sorry, wasn't quite clear about the fact that I still wanted the graph to be editable with GEF means, and use EditParts, etc.